# how to evenly layout the tab title using ActionBar (Android)

Tags: android-viewpager, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have a ViewPager and 3 tabs/fragments are attached to it. It's noticed that when switch between tabs, the title text of either far left or right tab will be cut. I would like to have the tab titles evenly spaced so that this cut won't occur. How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Shawn

screen shot attached:

[image]

Comment: Hi Shawn, can you attach screenshot or image for that for more details.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I attached the screen shot. As you can see, the third tab's text is cut off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Custom theme inside tab layout and you can easily manage your text size and many different properties.

Like : 
  app:tabMode="scrollable"

define inside tab layout.

Also, create a custom theme in style.

```
<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I follow you. I am using a fragment for each tab. Not sure when you said "tab layout". Can you elaborate how to apply your changes? Thanks.

Comment: TabLayout is not used in the app, it's ActionBar.